# Showing section numbers on beamer footline except 0

Tags: beamer

I'm working on a beamer presentation using the Madrid theme, and I've created my own footline. Everything is fine, but I would like to include section information in the footline beneath the title, specifically, something formatted like "Sec. # - Section Title", where # is the section number. I can do this just fine, except that before the first section I have "Sec. 0 - ", and I was wondering if there was a simple way of hiding this, or having it not display until the first section is reached.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{ amsmath, amssymb}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=true]

\definecolor{darkblue}{RGB}{0,0,120}

\setbeamercolor{author in head/foot}{fg=white,bg=black}
\setbeamercolor{title in head/foot}{fg=white,bg=darkerblue}
\setbeamercolor{date in head/foot}{fg=white,bg=darkblue}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=white,bg=darkblue}
\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{
  \leavevmode
  \hbox{

  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=4ex,left]{author in head/foot}% 
    \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}
        \begin{tabular}{l}
        \insertshortauthor\\
        \insertshortinstitute
        \end{tabular}
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=4ex,left]{title in head/foot}%

    \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}
        \vspace*{-2pt}
        \begin{tabular}{l}
        \insertshorttitle\\
        \insertsection~~\beamer@ifempty{\phantom{section}}{}{}
        \end{tabular}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
}
  \vskip0pt
}
\makeatother


\title{A Title}
\author{The Author}
\institute{The Institute}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Outline}
An outline.
\end{frame}

\section{The First Section}
\begin{frame}
A frame.
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Insert a query about the section number, if it is greater than zero, than insert the section number and title, otherwise leave that empty line, such that the surrounding `tabular` environment really prints out that row.

The query is easily done with the `\ifnumgreater` command from `etoolbox` package:

```
\ifnumgreater{\arabic{section}}{0}{% True branch
   Sec. \thesection~ -- \insertsection~~ \beamer@ifempty{\phantom{section}}{}{} % line 
}{% False branch
  ~~\beamer@ifempty{\phantom{section}}{}%  Empty fake row
}%
```

However, if there would be by chance `\chapter`s, the section counter would be reset to zero also and the first frames in a chapter appearing before the first section would show no section title, but this is probably wanted.

---

Here is the final code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{ amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{etoolbox}%
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=true]

\definecolor{darkblue}{RGB}{0,0,120}

\setbeamercolor{author in head/foot}{fg=white,bg=black}
\setbeamercolor{title in head/foot}{fg=white,bg=darkblue}
\setbeamercolor{date in head/foot}{fg=white,bg=darkblue}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=white,bg=darkblue}
\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{
  \leavevmode
  \hbox{

  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=4ex,left]{author in head/foot}% 
    \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}
        \begin{tabular}{l}
        \insertshortauthor\\
        \insertshortinstitute
        \end{tabular}
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=4ex,left]{title in head/foot}%

    \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}
        \vspace*{-2pt}
        \begin{tabular}{l}
        \insertshorttitle\\
        \ifnumgreater{\arabic{section}}{0}{Sec. \thesection~ -- \insertsection~~\beamer@ifempty{\phantom{section}}{}{}}{%
          ~~\beamer@ifempty{\phantom{section}}{}%
          }%
        \end{tabular}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
}
  \vskip0pt
}
\makeatother


\title{A Title}
\author{The Author}
\institute{The Institute}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Outline}
An outline.
\end{frame}

\section{The First Section}
\begin{frame}
A frame.
\end{frame}

\section{The Second Section}
\begin{frame}
Another frame.
\end{frame}

\section{Third Section}%
\begin{frame}
Yet Another frame.
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

**Title and frames before the first section -- unnumbered**
[image]

**Frames in a section, being numbered**
[image]